# Woocommerce variation links to different product

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to link different product when choosing variations in woocommerce? 
For example, if I'm choosing 'red' color for a T-Shirt, to send the customer to another product URL (the red T-shirt)?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it should be certainly possible…

Comment: do you have a suggestion how? or working example?

Comment: Sorry but this is a real advanced development and StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.